# Javascript: Dynamic Variables in For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, for-loop, dynamic

I am a javascript beginner and need your help! Thanks a lot for any help!

```
cell_660 = cell_638;
cell_659 = cell_637;
...
```

It worked that way. I now want to do this every second for all 660 variables to change their value to the value of the variable which name has the number (own number -22) at the end. Of course without writing 660 lines of code! I tried this so far:

```
var count = 660;

setInterval(function(){

for(var i=1;i<=660;i++){
    'cell_' + count = 'cell_' + eval(count - 22);
    count--;
}
count=660;

},1000);
```

How do I write this correctly? I already read about window['cell_' + count] - but I don't want to create 660 new variables every second. I want to CHANGE the value of 660 Variables every second.

Comment: this is not creating new variables.

Comment: The bracket syntax either creates *or updates* a variable with the dynamic name. Also, you don't need `eval`: just `'cell_' + (count - 22)`.

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey - I will try it again the way you described it - but doesnt javascript interpret >>>> 'cell_' + variable <<<<< as a string and not the value of an existing variablename?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use your previous `window['cell_' + count]` code. You should really read the answers to this question first though; having 600+ variables is definitely a sign of a bad design choice somewhere along the line.

Comment: I understand you are learning, but as you see, all answers below point to using arrays.  If you plan on doing any serious programming, you need to learn best practices and plan your code out (with paper and pencil even) before beginning anything on the computer.  Trust me, you will really appreciate the hours it saves avoiding thought and flow errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## with an array

how about having an array instead of this many variables ?

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

function moveArrElem() {
  // loop all elements of the array
  // using arr.map give us a buffer so current index are keeped while doing the modification
  arr = arr.map((_, i) => {
    
    // get the new index and make it valid if necessary
    let newIndex = i - 2; 
    if (newIndex < 0) {
      newIndex += arr.length
    }
    return arr[newIndex]
  })
  console.log(arr)
}

console.log(arr)
setInterval(moveArrElem, 2000)
```

about `window['cell_' + count]` it doesn't create a new variable each time, in fact `var test = 42` is equal to `window["test"] = 42` if you're in the global scope (outside of any functions and other blocks)

so `window['cell_' + count]` will just modify the value of the var

```js
var test = 42
console.log(window["test"])
```

finally try to avoid [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) as much as you can, it is slow and generally a security issue

some (I'm of these) a call to `eval` is almost always sign ther is a misconception elsewhere

---

## without array

since OP told in comment he still hasn't learned array, here's a solution without array

```js
let quantity = 660

// declaring the 660 vars
for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
  window["cell_" + i] = i;
}

function moveCells() {
  // need some tmp vars
  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    window["tmp_" + i] = window["cell_" + i];
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    let newIndex = i - 22
    if (newIndex < 0) {
      // equals to : newIndex = newIndex + quantity
      newIndex += quantity
    }
    window["cell_" + newIndex] = window["tmp_" + i];
  }

  // displaying 660 items would take to much time and place
  console.log("cell_42 : " + cell_42)
  console.log("cell_43 : " + cell_43)
  console.log("cell_44 : " + cell_44)
  console.log("cell_45 : " + cell_45)
  console.log("cell_46 : " + cell_46)
}

console.log("cell_42 : " + cell_42)
console.log("cell_43 : " + cell_43)
console.log("cell_44 : " + cell_44)
console.log("cell_45 : " + cell_45)
console.log("cell_46 : " + cell_46)

setInterval(moveCells, 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I haven't learned yet how to use arrays, and little about functions etc. so unfortunately your answer is too difficult for me to understand

Comment: @javascriptLearner arrays are needed if you want to use large number of variable like in this case, I'll add a way to do it without array at the end of my answer ;)

Comment: @javascriptLearner added a solution without array

Comment: thank you I managed to solve my problem with your help, thank you very much for the solution without arrays! Can I give you a "best answer" title or something? Im new to stackoverflow - however thanks a lot

Comment: @javascriptLearner you can mark the answer as `accepted` by clicking the green tick at the top left of the answser

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to change 660 variables every second?  What if you just create one numeric variable which keeps the location of "where in the array to start" when you display or use the array values?

```js
var cells = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

var currentStart = 0;

// create an interval to modify currentStart
setInterval(function () {
  currentStart = (currentStart + 22) % cells.length;
}, 1000);

function doSomething() {
  // display contents starting at currentStart
  var msg = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var index = (i + currentStart) % cells.length;
    // do something with cells[index]
    msg += "," + cells[index];
  }
  console.log(msg);
}

document.querySelector("#thing").addEventListener("click", doSomething);
```

```html
<button id='thing'>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I give you an answer, I'd first like to point out this is **terrible** code practice.  You should never need 660 variables!  Whatever you're trying to do could probably be accomplished with arrays.  That being said, here is how you would make this work, and how you should actually do this below.  I strongly recommend that you consider going with the array method!

```
setInterval(function() {
  for(var i = 660; i > 22; i--) {
    window['cell_' + i] = window['cell_' + (i - 22)];
  }
},1000);
```

Now here is something more along the lines of what you should actually be doing.

```
var cells = [/* 660 elements */];
setTimeout(function() {
  for(var i = 22; i < 660; i++) {
    cells[i] = cells[i - 22];
  }
}, 1000);
```

In fact, with this method, you can do the whole thing in one line with the new [`Array#copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin) method in ES6.

```
const cells = [/* 660 elements */];
setTimeout(() => {
  cells.copyWithin(22);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: the solution without arrays did it for me now and I solved my problem - I am learning how to use arrays in a couple of months and I would never use more than 20 variables for anything jobrelated - this was just an experiment, don't worry - thank you for your very clear and on-point answer